# Using git reset - does it remove commits - looking to save disk space

Tags: git, git-reset

If I have a bunch of merge commits on a branch, if I use

```
git reset --soft <old_sha>
```

will git remove/delete the commits between old_sha and the most current commit - git does garbage collection right? Just looking to save disk space.

Answer (score 2):

`git reset` only resets the HEAD to the specified state, see the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset).
You need the `git gc` command to delete the unnecessary objects from the disk. See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) for the details.